# Removing nulls from Pyspark Dataframe in individual columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like this:

`+--------------------+--------------------+
|                name|               value|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|
|                null|                null|
|                  id|                null|
|                name|                null|
|                 age|                null|
|                food|                null|
|                null|                   1|
|                null|                 Joe|
|                null|                  47|
|                null|               pizza|
+--------------------+--------------------+`

I want to remove the null values from each individual columns so the non-null data lines up.

The desired output is:

`+--------------------+--------------------+
|                name|               value|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  id|                   1|
|                name|                 Joe|
|                 age|                  47|
|                food|               pizza|
+--------------------+--------------------+`

I have tried removing nulls doing something like `df.dropna(how='any'/'all')` but and by separating out the columns and removing the nulls, but then it becomes difficult to join them back together.

Answer (score 1):

try this- written in scala, but can be ported to pyspark with minimal change

```scala
   df.select(map_from_arrays(collect_list("name").as("name"),
      collect_list("value").as("value")).as("map"))
      .select(explode_outer($"map").as(Seq("name", "value")))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----+-----+
      * |name|value|
      * +----+-----+
      * |id  |1    |
      * |name|Joe  |
      * |age |47   |
      * |food|pizza|
      * +----+-----+
      */
```

Comment: pyspark version of the same `(df.select(F.map_from_arrays(F.collect_list("name"),F.collect_list("value")).alias("map"))
.select(F.explode_outer("map").alias("name","value"))).show()` , very nicely done, learned something new.. +1